# Can´t return fibonacci sequence

Tags: java

I tried to return fibonacci sequence in java, but i have a problem with the values.

Example code.

```
@Override
public int fibonacci(int numero) throws RemoteException {
    int numero1 = 1;
    int numero2 = 0;
    int fibonacci = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= numero; i++) {
        fibonacci = numero1 + numero2;
        numero1 = numero2;
        numero2 = fibonacci;
        //return "La serie fibonnaci es:" + fibonacci;
    }
    return fibonacci;

}
```

Fibonacci variable return 0 but i need to return a fibonnaci sequence. ¿Any idea?

Comment: RMI has nothing to do with this question. Your remote method implementation doesn't need to be declared as throwing `Remote Exception.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two peoposals for your problem:

**Number one:** Print on screen

```
public static void fibonacci(int numero) {
    int numero1 = 0;
    int numero2 = 1;
    int fibonacci = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= numero; i++) {
        fibonacci = numero1 + numero2;
        numero1 = numero2;
        numero2 = fibonacci;
        System.out.println(fibonacci);
    }
}
```

**Number two** *(better in my opinion)*: Return list

```
public static List<Integer> fibonacci(int numero) {
    LinkedList<Integer> fibonacciSequence = new LinkedList<>();
    int numero1 = 0;
    int numero2 = 1;
    int fibonacci = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= numero; i++) {
        fibonacci = numero1 + numero2;
        numero1 = numero2;
        numero2 = fibonacci;
        fibonacciSequence.add(fibonacci);
    }
    return fibonacciSequence;
}
```

Comment: The fibonacci method implements interface so need this return :$

Comment: Then use the second one

Comment: One question ¿Why LinkedList and not Arraylist?

Comment: Does not matter which one you take, as both implement `List` interface. You can also use ArrayList. It might even be more accurate since the length of the list is known in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You switched `numero1` and `numero2` during the initialization.

This should fix it:

```
int numero1 = 0;
int numero2 = 1;
```

Comment: Right, but does not solve OP's problem.